# Why couldn't Alice enter the Horenvendush Day wave the first time?

Tags: disney, alice-in-wonderland, through-the-looking-glass

While riding in the Chronosphere, Alice comes across Horenvendush Day. However, when she tries to enter it, she's bounced back violently and enters another day (I forget which), in which she sees the attempted coronation of the Red Queen. Aside from "plot", what was the reason she was rejected from entering the Horenvendush Day wave the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I believe she was knocked off course by

> Time

who was pursuing her.